# Display multiple input image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to display my multiple input image on my html page

this is my input code

```
<img src="img/package_thumbnail.png" class="myAvatar">
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="" style="display: inline;" /><br><br>
<input type="file" name="newAvatar" id="newAvatar" style="display: none;" onchange="readURL(this);" required />

<script>
   $(".myAvatar").click(function() {
     $("#newAvatar").trigger("click");
   });
</script>
```

then this is my script to display single image

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

i want to improve it to display multiple image, anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload new image just create clone of your dom image element and update src.

Change your function from

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

TO

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
             $new_img = $('#blah').clone().attr('src', e.target.result).width(150).height(200);
             $new_img.insertAfter($('#blah'));
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet. IN this it checks if it as one blank src image then it will update url of that image and if it doesn't contain blank url image means it already contains uploaded image then it will clone that image and update url. And I also updated your html. I just changed id="blah" to class="blah". So when uploading multiple images it doesn't contain duplicate id.

```js
  $(".myAvatar").click(function() {
     $("#newAvatar").trigger("click");
   });
   
   
   function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if($("img[src='#']").length == 1)
            {
              $('.blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
            }
            else
            {
              $new_img = $('.blah:first').clone().attr('src', e.target.result).width(150).height(200);
              $new_img.insertAfter($('.blah:last'));
            }
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/package_thumbnail.png" class="myAvatar">
<img class="blah" src="#" alt="" style="display: inline;" /><br><br>
<input type="file" name="newAvatar" id="newAvatar" style="display: none;" onchange="readURL(this);" required />
```